# How to stop an uploading file to GCS in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to stop an uploading file
Here is my code:

```js
const uploadFile = async ({ bucketName, filePath, destFileName }) => {
  const storage = new Storage();
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filePath, {
    destination: destFileName,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, it looks like you can stop only a [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#cancel-upload):

> Use cURL to call the JSON API with a DELETE request:
>
> ```
> curl -i -X DELETE -H "Content-Length: 0" \
>   "SESSION_URI"
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> `SESSION_URI` is the value returned in the `Location` header when you
> initiated the resumable upload. If successful, the response contains a
> `499` status code. Future attempts to query or resume the upload
> result in a `4xx` response.